# NodeJS Twitter API get liked tweets count

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, twitter-api-v2, twitter-api-v1

I'm trying to get the number of tweets a user has ever liked in NodeJs using twitter-api-v2, but I can't seem to find the solution. I tried to use the "public_metrics" property but it looks like it only contains the following properties:

- followers count
- following count
- tweet count
- listed count

I also tried to use the client.v2.userLikedTweets() method but it can only go up to 100 likes, I know I could upgrade to a premium account but I don't want to

Is there a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Premium would not help as it only provides greater access to search, not to user metrics. I don't believe there is a solution here at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an elevated access, you can use the `favourites_count` field in the `User` objects from the Twitter API V1. But there is unfortunately no way to do so with the Twitter API V2.

Comment: damn I guess I'll have to do it in a very hacky way then, like reading the HTML file

Comment: @Redy Applying to an elevated access seems easier and more reliable but yes, that could also be a solution.